# Determine the probability that exactly two hearts turn up.

Tags: probability

A card is drawn four times from a regular deck, with replacement each time. Determine the probability that exactly two hearts turn up.

Comment: take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: The principle of this site is that we are awaiting you to say what you have attempted, where you are blocked, etc. Please, do not post again raw questions without any comment.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the binominal distribution to solve this.

Probability of $k$ successes from $n$ trails with probability $p$ is.

$$P(X = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

We have that the probability of a success is $P(\mathrm{heart}) = \frac{1}{4}$

Thus subbing into our formula we have $$ P(X = 2) = \binom{4}{2}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\left(1-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{2} \approx 0.2109$$

Comment: thank you! this helped alot

Comment: @ojlm You are free to do what you want by I bring to your attention that this OP has asked 3 questions, all of them without any comment. One should be very careful not to encourage an attitude of "having all without effort". It is not good for her, it encourages a form of laziness.

Comment: @JeanMarie I hadn't noticed but thanks. I'm trying to answer as many questions as I can so I get enough reputation to raise awareness for my own latest question :)

Comment: I understand. Interesting questions besides.